# awk: Handle positions with NR in a if loop. Next and previous position

Tags: if-statement, awk

I have this line into my bash script.

```
#Trying to find the FIRST maximum in the column $10
awk 'BEGIN{max=0} {if($10>=max){max=$10} else{exit}}  END{print NR}'
```

And it works.

But I need something more sophisticated (for another purpose). I need to awk to check if the next and the previous row values are higher than the actual one (something like this):

```
awk 'BEGIN{max=0} {if($10[NR]>=max && $10[NR-1]>=$10[NR] && $10[NR+1]>=$10[NR] ){max=$10} else{exit}}  END{print NR}'
```

But it doesn't work, probably because I don't know how to handle the positions in the column. Can you help me please?

---

Clarification:

I just want to read a column completely (column 10) and find the row number which has a higher value in the previous row and the next row. For instance if the column has the values 1,2,3,4,1,2 then I want to get the row number "5" (corresponding to the second 1 in the data) because it is the row in the column which has two higher values next to it.

Comment: You can't usefully compare with `[NR+1]` because that row hasn't been read yet.  So, you must first rework the problem in terms of `[NR-2]`, `[NR-1]` and `[NR]`.  Having said that, I'd probably not try keeping all the values in an array; I'd only keep the previous and previous but one values.  I'm not clear you can use `$10[NR]`; it is a very unusual array name.  What is your requirement?  It really isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.ay be there is another way to do it. I just want to read a column completely and find the row at which has two higher values in the previous row and the next one. For instance if the column has this values: 1,2,3,4,1,2 then i want to get the number "5" because is the position in the column which has two higher values next to it.

Comment: So you want each local minimum printed?  Given a longer stream of numbers, each time there's a local minimum, you'd want its row number identified.  And the values are in column 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ if ($10 > old1 && old1 < old2) print NR-1; old2 = old1; old1 = $10; }'
```

To test, I replaced `$10` with `$1`.  Run on this data:

```
1
2
3
4
3
4
5
4
3
2
1
2
3
4
5
4
5
4
3
2
1
```

It produces this output:

```
5
11
16
```

Comment: Exactly! I will test it tomorrow but I think that this does the job! Thanks man.

Comment: Can I ask you why this work?. I mean since.you never define old1 and old2 at the begining it shouldnt satisfy never the if condition. Butnobviously it does...

Comment: As to old1, old2; they are automagically set to 0 when you first use them.  As long as your data is not negative, it'll work fine.  If the inputs can be negative, then you need to set `old1` and `old2` in a `BEGIN` block, probably to a large negative integer (more negative than anything in your data).  Or you could use `NR==1` and set them both to the value in the first record.   Incidentally, if you want to stop after the first local minimum, simply put the `print NR-1;` inside braces with an `exit`, as in: `if (...) { print NR-1; exit }`

Comment: Thanks again Jonathan, I tried the code and works perfectly. And actually I need the last minimum founded. How can I do it?

Comment: I was trying to take the last NR-1 found but I can't.

Comment: If you need the last minimum, then (a) don't print in the main code, (b) save NR-1 in variable `lastmin`, and (c) add an END block which does print `lastmin`.

Comment: Thanks again, it works perfectly. The final code is then: 
awk '{ if ($10 > old1 && old1 < old2) lastmin=NR-1; old2 = old1; old1 = $10; } END{print lastmin}'